# Python array manipulation, splitting, deleting

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array to which i would like to add 1's to the last column of the first 16 rows and 0's to the last column of rows from 17 to 27. I searched everywhere however splitting seems to work only when we want to split the array into even parts, if i could cut the array at a specific row into two smaller arrays it would be easy because i would just append 1's and 0's than bring the arrays together again.

Another option would be to hard code where the specific numbers should go by indexing but that seems a bit complicated

frankly i don't have any more ideas for it, here are the arrays for visual representation of the problem (with shortened rows):

```
[[0.133987 0.359897 0.000000 0.527855 0.764706 0.212121]
[0.301506 0.407752 0.013970 0.553386 0.830450 0.272727]
[0.414438 0.415456 0.023283 0.597853 0.833910 0.333333]
[0.434815 0.415844 0.046566 0.604616 0.837370 0.363636]
[0.436664 0.500333 0.093132 0.607321 0.868512 0.366667]
[0.447560 0.559649 0.098952 0.626934 0.882353 0.393939]]
```

I would like to have it like so:`

```
[[0.133987 0.359897 0.000000 0.527855 0.764706 0.212121 1]
[0.301506 0.407752 0.013970 0.553386 0.830450 0.272727 1]
[0.414438 0.415456 0.023283 0.597853 0.833910 0.333333 1]
[0.434815 0.415844 0.046566 0.604616 0.837370 0.363636 1]
[0.436664 0.500333 0.093132 0.607321 0.868512 0.366667 0]
[0.447560 0.559649 0.098952 0.626934 0.882353 0.393939 0]]
```

Comment: Do you have an array, a list of lists, or a numpy array? Each has its own solutions.

Comment: You describe your attempts, but it may be helpful to see some actual code of your (best) attempt.

Comment: it's a numpy array, I didn't try anything because i haven't found any method for it so i don't even know where to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably a cleaner more efficient way to do this but I think this is what you are after.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[0.133987, 0.359897, 0.000000, 0.527855, 0.764706, 0.212121], [0.301506, 0.407752, 0.013970, 0.553386, 0.830450, 0.272727], [0.414438, 0.415456, 0.023283, 0.597853, 0.833910, 0.333333], [0.434815, 0.415844, 0.046566, 0.604616, 0.837370, 0.363636], [0.436664, 0.500333, 0.093132, 0.607321, 0.868512, 0.366667], [0.447560, 0.559649, 0.098952, 0.626934, 0.882353, 0.393939]])

extra = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    if i < 3:
        extra.append([1])
    else:
        extra.append([0])

extra = np.array(extra)

result = np.hstack([data, extra])

print(result)
```

resulting in

```
[[ 0.133987  0.359897  0.        0.527855  0.764706  0.212121  1.      ]
 [ 0.301506  0.407752  0.01397   0.553386  0.83045   0.272727  1.      ]
 [ 0.414438  0.415456  0.023283  0.597853  0.83391   0.333333  1.      ]
 [ 0.434815  0.415844  0.046566  0.604616  0.83737   0.363636  0.      ]
 [ 0.436664  0.500333  0.093132  0.607321  0.868512  0.366667  0.      ]
 [ 0.44756   0.559649  0.098952  0.626934  0.882353  0.393939  0.      ]]
```

Comment: `extra = [[int(i < len(data) // 2)] for i in range(len(data))]` would be nicer. And either `//` or `/` depending on which portion of odd half should have 1 or 0.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an abridged version which takes an input with 4 rows and adds `1` to the first 2 rows and `0` to the remaining rows. You would only have to adjust the numbers to fit your requirements.

```
v = [[0.133987, 0.359897, 0.000000, 0.527855, 0.764706, 0.212121],
     [0.301506, 0.407752, 0.013970, 0.553386, 0.830450, 0.272727],
     [0.414438, 0.415456, 0.023283, 0.597853, 0.833910, 0.333333],
     [0.447560, 0.559649, 0.098952, 0.626934, 0.882353, 0.393939]]

print('before **********')
for line in v:
 print(line)

for i, x in enumerate(v):
    if i < 2:
        x.append(1) # did you want ints here or floats to be consistent?
    else:
        x.append(0)

print('after **********')
for line in v:
    print(line)
```

output:

```
before **********
[0.133987, 0.359897, 0.0, 0.527855, 0.764706, 0.212121]
[0.301506, 0.407752, 0.01397, 0.553386, 0.83045, 0.272727]
[0.414438, 0.415456, 0.023283, 0.597853, 0.83391, 0.333333]
[0.44756, 0.559649, 0.098952, 0.626934, 0.882353, 0.393939]
after **********
[0.133987, 0.359897, 0.0, 0.527855, 0.764706, 0.212121, 1]
[0.301506, 0.407752, 0.01397, 0.553386, 0.83045, 0.272727, 1]
[0.414438, 0.415456, 0.023283, 0.597853, 0.83391, 0.333333, 0]
[0.44756, 0.559649, 0.098952, 0.626934, 0.882353, 0.393939, 0]
```

You could also shorten the append line to

```
x.append(1 if i < 2 else 0)
```

If you so wished.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the last column and concatenate them:

```
arr = np.random.random(size=(27,6))
flag = [0]*16 + [1]*11
flag = np.array([flag])
arr_ = np.concatenate([arr, flag.T], axis=1)
```

The elements of a numpy array must have uniform dtypes, so you actually get 1. and 0. in the last column